# DateTimePicker value from DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datetimepicker

I have some textboxes and a datetimepicker. There is also a datagridview on it. I upload data to a mysql table. I want to modify the data via textboxes and datetimepicker, but I get error:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException

on the dateTimePicker.Value row:

```
private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  dateTimePicker1.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value);

  idoTextBox.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
  pkcomboBox.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
  minositesbox.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
  esetextBox.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
  fotextBox.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
  megjegyzestextBox.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[7].Value.ToString();
}
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/raw/aEeApfVX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't have a *row* selected, just a cell.

Make sure you have the correct SelectionMode property set:

```
dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
```

Also, make sure you have selected rows:

```
if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0) {
  dateTimePicker1.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value);
  // ...
}
```

Comment: FullRowSelect property is selected. The data display on other textbox correctly when I choose a row.

Comment: @GaborVirag What kind of value do you have in the grid for your date value?

Comment: My grid gets data from a mysql table. It's type "date".

Comment: @GaborVirag Updated post.  The only other possibility I can see is that you aren't checking that SelectedRows actually *has* rows.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` which means that you are most likely trying to access a value that does not exist at your specified index. You are probably doing this while calling

```
dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[7].Value.ToString();
```

You are using a cell index of 7 right here, is it possible that Cells[7] does not exist?

Comment: I have 8 cells in dataGridView1. I want to insert all data to textboxes and dateTimePicker instead of the ID cell at first place. I changed the code to remove the Id column from dataGridView at first place. The error occurs when I click the insert button and data are uploded. I think dataGridView cell number start at 0. The "date" data is at first place in dataGridView. How can I upload a picture from the error?

Comment: You could upload the text from the error to something like pastebin and post the link right here.

Comment: When I insert into data to the db table I insert dateTimePicker1.Value.Date because want to see just date. However at dataGridView1_SelectionChanged event the value of dateTimePicker1 contain date and time (00:00). Whether is it the fault or not? I dont know. I have been trying to get rid this problem but I dont know what is the fault.

Comment: How are you storing the date in your db table? Is it a datetime? You should switch it to date column type, which stores only the date part of the datetime, e.g. only 2016.12.2 without the 00:00 part.

Comment: Its type of date in the table. :(

Comment: How are you inserting the dates into `dataGridView1`? Try this: `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`.

Comment: First of all i insert data by a simple query:                                         <!-- language: c# -->
string rogzit = "INSERT INTO events(id, date, time, pk, minosites, eset, fo, megjegyzes)VALUES('','"+dateTimePicker1.Value.Date+"','"+idoTextBox.Text+"','"+pkcomboBox.Text+"','"+minositesbox.Text+"','"+Convert.ToInt16(esetextBox.Text)+"','"+Convert.ToInt16(fotextBox.Text)+"','"+megjegyzestextBox.Text+"')";